# Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission. error message

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

i have using swiftmailer. I have also included  in all my layout files.
i am facing a problem

> Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission.

it work's fine with single file but when i select multiple file it shows the error message
Bad Request (#400)
Unable to verify your data submission.

please help me to solve the problem

Comment: what do you want to do? what is expected output explain in detail also show us what you did

Comment: i want to select multiple file at once to upload it on server

<?= $form->field($custModel, "fileUpload[$custModel->document_id][]")->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
       'options'=>['multiple' => true],
       'pluginOptions'=>[
        'showUpload'=>false,
       ],
      ])->label(Yii::$app->params['required_docs'][$custModel->document_id]);
     ?>

Comment: post your controller code and rules also

Comment: rules-  [['fileUpload'], 'file','maxFiles' => 5],it's not even entering in controller.

Comment: sounds like problems with csrf. try turning off for your action in your controller with:

public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'my-method') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
echo $form->field($model, 'fileUpload[$custModel->document_id][]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true],
    'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png']
])->label(Yii::$app->params['required_docs'][$custMode‌​l->document_id]);
```

your rule should look like this

```
[['fileUpload'], 'safe'],
[['fileUpload'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png','maxFiles' => 5],
```

and in your controller action, make sure that you are using

```
$images = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'fileUpload'); // not getInstance
```

Comment: have you defined access rules properly?

Comment: public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    } need to make some changes ?

Comment: all seems to be right.. I think you must set these **post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_input_time** in your `php.ini` file. issue is occuring due to large size upload data

Comment: post_max_size = 20MB,upload_max_filesize=20MB,max_input_time=60 (also tried with max_input_time= -1)

Comment: increase your post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to more and restart your httpd service or wamp if you are on windows. changes will get reflect only after restart of services